# Maximum transfer rate iSCSI bonding vs multipath

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, linux-networking, iscsi

I want to get the maximum tranfer rate with iSCSI from my virtual machine (Linux) to my Linux Storage Host.
I don't know iSCSi well so I'm not sure which way is the best for performance.

A: Just create one iSCSI session from vmnic0 to the bond0 interface of the storage host. But then I won't get more than 1Gbps
And

(I'm not sure if there is even a way to get really more than 1Gbps for a 
single file transfer, probably not).

B: Should I create additional vmnic's? and configure multipath?
   Does multipath even make sense from a virtual machine over an esxi host which does already bonding?

setup:

```
     |-------|                   
     |  VM   |
     |-------|    
         |
      vmnic0
     (VMXNET3)
         |
      vSwitch
         |
     |-------|            
     | ESXi  | 
     |-------|   
         | 
 {Route by IP Hash, 
  Trunk 4 NIC Active}
         |
---------------------
 |     |    |    |
nic0 nic1 nic2 nic3
 |     |    |    |
     |-------|            
     |Switch | 
     |-------|   
 |     |    |    |
eth0 eth1 eth2  eth3
 |     |    |    |
---------------------
         | 
   {LACP Bonding}
         |
   |------------|            
   | Linux      |
   | Sorage Host| 
   |------------|
```